# Как нарисовать гистограмму по вводимым данным?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Нужно нарисовать гистограмму по вводимым данным. С помощью каких методов можно передавать данные из текстовых полей, чтобы нарисовать гистограмму

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItemCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SubCategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.GradientPaintTransformType;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.StandardGradientPaintTransformer;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BarChartStacked extends ApplicationFrame {



    public BarChartStacked(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

        chartPanel.add(new JButton("one"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }


    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(19.4, "Product 1 (Europe)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(10.9, "Product 1 (Europe)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(18.4, "Product 1 (Europe)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(16.5, "Product 1 (Asia)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(15.9, "Product 1 (Asia)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(16.1, "Product 1 (Asia)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(13.2, "Product 1 (Middle East)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Product 1 (Middle East)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(13.7, "Product 1 (Middle East)", "Mar 04");

        result.addValue(23.3, "Product 2 (US)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(16.2, "Product 2 (US)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(28.7, "Product 2 (US)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(12.7, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(17.9, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(12.6, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(15.4, "Product 2 (Asia)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(21.0, "Product 2 (Asia)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(11.1, "Product 2 (Asia)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(23.8, "Product 2 (Middle East)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(23.4, "Product 2 (Middle East)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(19.3, "Product 2 (Middle East)", "Mar 04");

        result.addValue(11.9, "Product 3 (US)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(31.0, "Product 3 (US)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(22.7, "Product 3 (US)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(15.3, "Product 3 (Europe)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Product 3 (Europe)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(25.3, "Product 3 (Europe)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(23.9, "Product 3 (Asia)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(19.0, "Product 3 (Asia)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(10.1, "Product 3 (Asia)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(13.2, "Product 3 (Middle East)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(15.5, "Product 3 (Middle East)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(10.1, "Product 3 (Middle East)", "Mar 04");

        return result;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Stacked Bar Chart Demo 4",  // chart title
                "Category",                  // domain axis label
                "Value",                     // range axis label
                dataset,                     // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,    // the plot orientation
                true,                        // legend
                true,                        // tooltips
                false                        // urls
        );

        GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
        KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (US)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Europe)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Asia)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Middle East)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (US)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Europe)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Asia)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Middle East)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (US)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (Europe)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (Asia)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (Middle East)", "G3");
        renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);

        renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);

        Paint p1 = new Color(255, 0, 0);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, p1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, p1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(8, p1);

        Paint p2 = new Color(0, 255, 0);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, p2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(5, p2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(9, p2);

        Paint p3 = new Color(0, 0, 255);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, p3);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(6, p3);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(10, p3);

        Paint p4 = new Color(140, 0, 210);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, p4);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(7, p4);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(11, p4);
        renderer.setGradientPaintTransformer(
                new StandardGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformType.HORIZONTAL)
        );

        SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Product / Month");
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05);
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 1");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 2");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 3");

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        //plot.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setFixedLegendItems(createLegendItems());
        return chart;

    }

    private LegendItemCollection createLegendItems() {
        LegendItemCollection result = new LegendItemCollection();

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BarChartStacked demo = new BarChartStacked("Stacked Bar Chart Demo 4");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Данный код рисует фиксированную гистограмму, а я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы можно было по задающимся параметрам из TextArea или TextField можно было рисовать саму гистограмму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте JTextArea на панель фрейма:

```java
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setColumns(10);
chartPanel.add(textArea);
```

После чего создайте кнопку, которая будет генерировать отчет по нажатию, обработчик нажатия этой кнопки и добавьте данную кнопку на панель:

```java
JButton generateButton = new JButton("generate");
generateButton.addActionListener(e -> generateChart());
chartPanel.add(generateButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Метод `generateChart` будет генерировать новую гистограмму на основе введенных данных в textArea и обновлять содержимое фрейма:

```java
 private void generateChart(){
        final CategoryDataset dataset = readDatasetFromTextArea();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        this.getContentPane().removeAll();
        this.getContentPane().add(chartPanel);
        this.revalidate();
    }
```

И, наконец, метод `readDatasetFromTextArea`, который считывает содержимое textArea и генерирует набор данных на его основе.
Вы не указали желаемый формат ввода данных, поэтому я позволил себе выбрать следующий: в трёх строках в textArea должны следовать три показателя конкретного продукта за 3 разных месяца через пробел, например:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
4.5 3.7 1.1
2.3 3.4 1.1
```

Сам метод:

```java
    private CategoryDataset readDatasetFromTextArea() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        String[] lines = textArea.getText().split("\\n");
        String[] months = new String[] {"Jan 04", "Feb 04", "Mar 04"};
        String[] products = new String[] {"Product 1 (US)", "Product 2 (US)", "Product 3 (US)"};
        int currentProductIndex = 0;
        //цикл по индивидуальным строкам из TextArea
        for (String productRates : lines){
            int currentMonth = 0;
            String[] individualProductRates = productRates.split(" ");
            //цикл по показателям конкретного продукта в строке
            for (String rate : individualProductRates){
                Double value = Double.parseDouble(rate);
                result.addValue(value, products[currentProductIndex], months[currentMonth]);
                currentMonth++;
            }
            currentProductIndex++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Полный пример кода: (обратите внимание, что я использовал [jfreechart версии 1.5.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.5.3), поэтому API в импортах может немного отличаться)

```html
package jfreechart;

import java.awt.*;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItemCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SubCategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GroupedStackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.GradientPaintTransformType;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.StandardGradientPaintTransformer;
import org.jfree.data.KeyToGroupMap;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;


import javax.swing.*;

public class BarChartStacked extends ApplicationFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public BarChartStacked(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setColumns(10);
        chartPanel.add(textArea);

        setContentPane(chartPanel);

        JButton generateButton = new JButton("generate");
        generateButton.addActionListener(e -> generateChart());
        chartPanel.add(new JButton("one"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chartPanel.add(generateButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void generateChart(){
        final CategoryDataset dataset = readDatasetFromTextArea();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        this.getContentPane().removeAll();
        this.getContentPane().add(chartPanel);
        this.revalidate();
    }

    private CategoryDataset readDatasetFromTextArea() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        String[] lines = textArea.getText().split("\\n");
        String[] months = new String[] {"Jan 04", "Feb 04", "Mar 04"};
        String[] products = new String[] {"Product 1 (US)", "Product 2 (US)", "Product 3 (US)"};
        int currentProductIndex = 0;
        //цикл по индивидуальным строкам из TextArea
        for (String productRates : lines){
            int currentMonth = 0;
            String[] individualProductRates = productRates.split(" ");
            //цикл по показателям конкретного продукта в строке
            for (String rate : individualProductRates){
                Double value = Double.parseDouble(rate);
                result.addValue(value, products[currentProductIndex], months[currentMonth]);
                currentMonth++;
            }
            currentProductIndex++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset result = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        result.addValue(20.3, "Product 1 (US)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(27.2, "Product 1 (US)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(19.7, "Product 1 (US)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(19.4, "Product 1 (Europe)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(10.9, "Product 1 (Europe)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(18.4, "Product 1 (Europe)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(16.5, "Product 1 (Asia)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(15.9, "Product 1 (Asia)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(16.1, "Product 1 (Asia)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(13.2, "Product 1 (Middle East)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Product 1 (Middle East)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(13.7, "Product 1 (Middle East)", "Mar 04");

        result.addValue(23.3, "Product 2 (US)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(16.2, "Product 2 (US)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(28.7, "Product 2 (US)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(12.7, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(17.9, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(12.6, "Product 2 (Europe)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(15.4, "Product 2 (Asia)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(21.0, "Product 2 (Asia)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(11.1, "Product 2 (Asia)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(23.8, "Product 2 (Middle East)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(23.4, "Product 2 (Middle East)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(19.3, "Product 2 (Middle East)", "Mar 04");

        result.addValue(11.9, "Product 3 (US)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(31.0, "Product 3 (US)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(22.7, "Product 3 (US)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(15.3, "Product 3 (Europe)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(14.4, "Product 3 (Europe)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(25.3, "Product 3 (Europe)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(23.9, "Product 3 (Asia)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(19.0, "Product 3 (Asia)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(10.1, "Product 3 (Asia)", "Mar 04");
        result.addValue(13.2, "Product 3 (Middle East)", "Jan 04");
        result.addValue(15.5, "Product 3 (Middle East)", "Feb 04");
        result.addValue(10.1, "Product 3 (Middle East)", "Mar 04");

        return result;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Stacked Bar Chart Demo 4",  // chart title
                "Category",                  // domain axis label
                "Value",                     // range axis label
                dataset,                     // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,    // the plot orientation
                true,                        // legend
                true,                        // tooltips
                false                        // urls
        );

        GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
        KeyToGroupMap map = new KeyToGroupMap("G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (US)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Europe)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Asia)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 1 (Middle East)", "G1");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (US)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Europe)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Asia)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 2 (Middle East)", "G2");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (US)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (Europe)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (Asia)", "G3");
        map.mapKeyToGroup("Product 3 (Middle East)", "G3");
        renderer.setSeriesToGroupMap(map);

        renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);

        Paint p1 = new Color(255, 0, 0);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, p1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, p1);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(8, p1);

        Paint p2 = new Color(0, 255, 0);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, p2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(5, p2);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(9, p2);

        Paint p3 = new Color(0, 0, 255);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, p3);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(6, p3);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(10, p3);

        Paint p4 = new Color(140, 0, 210);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, p4);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(7, p4);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(11, p4);
        renderer.setGradientPaintTransformer(
                new StandardGradientPaintTransformer(GradientPaintTransformType.HORIZONTAL)
        );

        SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("Product / Month");
        domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05);
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 1");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 2");
        domainAxis.addSubCategory("Product 3");

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        //plot.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setFixedLegendItems(createLegendItems());
        return chart;

    }

    private LegendItemCollection createLegendItems() {
        LegendItemCollection result = new LegendItemCollection();

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BarChartStacked demo = new BarChartStacked("Stacked Bar Chart Demo 4");
        demo.pack();
        //RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```